Get a typedef name as a string
I have typedef'ed names (maybe within a class or not), and I want a method typedef_type to get one such name from an object of that type.
E.g., I want that after this snippet,
typedef int my_int;
my_int i;
std::string my_typedef = typedef_type(i);

my_typedef contains "my_int".
With the tools that I know (typeid with demangling),
my_typedef would contain "int", which in my use cases turn out to be very long strings, with nested maps, vectors, etc., and therefore illegible.
EDIT: I want to be able to print those names/aliases. Printing the  original types would be clumsy/almost useless. In addition to being shorter, the aliases are more meaningful (even though that is not the only reason for using typedef). This is a basic premise of good programming practice, so why would that not apply to interaction via output messages?
How can I achieve this?
I mean to have a non- or minimally- invasive code, i.e., something that would not require modifications across all headers that define my typedefs.
Or if need be, some minimal modifications, since I have a package with a large number of sources.
Related:

How to use typeid to get the type name which defined use typedef  Note: The present OP is clearly not a dupe of that one, since that focuses on typeid (and that alone cannot do the job).


a typedef is just an alias for an existing name, it doesn't introduce a new type, just a new name for an existing type.

If that is ever possible, it would be with compiler specific tools (like clang AST). Though I'm not sure it preserves name aliases in any way.

As described this appears to be an xy-problem.  What's the real problem you're trying to solve?

How do you feel about waiting optimistically for reflection?

Your post leaves impression that you want to give shorter textual runtime nicknames to types. You can do that but you need to use some self-implemented feature. The type aliases are what code can use as equivalent to original type, not texts that your program can output runtime.

@NathanOliver - I know that. But that per se doesn't mean there is no way to achieve what I want. The question I guess it is what is the least invasive way of doing that.

@ÖöTiib - That is exactly what I want. In addition to being shorter, they are more meaningful. This is a basic premise of good programming practice, so why would that not apply to interaction via output messages?

@G.M. - I don't think it is an xy problem. Just in case, I added a brief edit, with the real problem stated more explicitly (I though it was clear enough). Please let me know if this clarifies the objective.

Side note: Don't use typedef in modern C++, use using instead - it can do the same and more. typedef is obsolete.

@sancho.s As others have pointed out, C++ doesn't support this and aliases (typedefs) are just synonyms for actual types, not types in their own right. C++ doesn't even support getting the user friendly name of actual types let alone aliases. Functions like the "abi::__cxa_demangle()" that you pointed out in your link (or others like "UnDecorateSymbolName()" in MSVC) are not standard, and they're also runtime functions which are ugly for this purpose (IMHO).

@sancho.s Note that even compile time techniques like "TypeName_v in my own (free) library here (click "TypeName_v" at top of page to expand it), also rely on ugly techniques to get the job done (since there is no other way), but a call like TypeName_v<my_int> which returns a (compile-time) "std::basic_string_view" will still return "int", not "my_int". Upshot is you just can't do it using any [un]conventional technique I've ever heard of. If you really must do it then create new wrapper types as others have pointed out.

"This is a basic premise of good programming practice". Up to a point. Inventing your own "types" (even if they're just aliases) might end up complicating things and not writing portable code (i.e. something written for your framework would not work copy-pasted to a different framework). You'd always need to replace-all and do regression tests just to use your code in another framework. I won't even mention the different integral types like stdints uint32_t, MS ones (TCHAR, DWORD or intrinsics like __int32), "situational" ones (std::size_t, std::ptrdiff_t) etc.

@JesperJuhl - That may be true for new code. For existing code, I wouldn't start messing with a search-and-replace. And that is what I need it for.

@Larry - I know demangle is not standard. That is why I wrote code which detects the platform, etc., and uses whatever demangling is available (perhaps none).
And I agree with what you say. Still, I am asking for the "least invasive" method available, whatever that is.

@TheNomad - Using typedef appropriately should not lead to non-portable code.
On the contrary, if used appropriately, it provides for simplified code and functionality in many aspects, code less prone to errors, easier to maintain, etc. Readability is but one of the advantages provided.
The problematic case you envision stems from inappropriate copy-pasting, instead of #include. You provide a typedef and including your header will always work.

I only use local aliases in code for templates (as you said, readability). But not globally. As for not-leading to non-portable code, I disagree, if, for instance, you alias int to i32 and I'd fill all my codebase with it and I have to switch to a different lib, then I would have to replace all your typedefs. Why reinvent the wheel? There is a reason why a lot of things are standardized and integrated in "pure" C++ and why <cstdint> exists. But let's not get off-track as it's subjective. Regarding your question, it's not possible without typeid, except with "hacks" as shown by others.

@sancho.s I hear you, but since there is no way to do it without resorting to extraordinary means (I'd be surprised if you find a way, let alone one that doesn't come with a lot of baggage), "least invasive" implies you're still willing to live with it (rather than abandon the idea until reflection in C++26, which may provide a way, I don't know, though I'm skeptical).

@sancho.s Note BTW that if you're going to rely on demangling functions in any case, you may want to consider using a compile-time technique instead, such as the "TypeName_v" template I mentioned in my own library. Others exist as well you can find, though my own implementation is a solid choice (given the inherently brittle nature of the techniques all these implementations rely on - if done right they should be very stable though). If you want to take the situation offline let me know.

This cannot be done.
C++ doesn't have any "reasonable" reflection capabilities (that is, getting information about the source code). While you can get types as strings, and then demangle them to make them pretty, a typedef in particular is just a shortcut for another name -- the compiler completely eliminates all of it, and just uses the type that it refers to. It might still survive in the debug symbols, but there's no library (that I'm aware of) using this for reflection purposes, and it would stop working on a release build.

which in my use cases turn out to be very long strings, with nested maps, vectors, etc., and therefore illegible.

Well, I certainly get you, but that's just how it is. In fact, I have code that uses a boost library to pretty-print typenames for logging purposes -- and that boost library crashes on types created by one of the libraries that I'm using because that library creates crazy types that don't even fit on just one screen. I've actually made a wrapper for the boost typename prettyprinting, and just output those crazy names as mangled strings -- they aren't readable, but at least the code doesn't crash anymore.
You just have to work with what you have. If it's not perfect, then so be it.

I don't see a realistic way to get the name of a typedef without some kind of preprocessing of your source code which would be quite expensive. However you could create a wrapper around your type instead of just a typedef and use the preprocessor to create a wrapper for whatever type you need. If compiled with optimizations enabled it should have hardly any impacts on performance if any.
When you are using the wrapper in an expression which requires the underlying type T the conversion operator will be called. If the expression requires the wrapper for T or has an overload/is templated for it, then the type of the wrapper will be used. This allows you to use a variable which is of type wrapper for int in calculations as well as in typeid() and get your expected results.
You can add additional conversion operators for const T& or T&& if you need to. Some functions, especially templated ones, will allow both types which means that you might have to do some explicit casting.
#include <iostream>

#define CREATE_NAME_WRAPPER(Name, T)\
class Name {\
public:\
    Name(T value) : data{ value } {};\
    Name() {};\
    operator T& () {\
        return data;\
    }\
private:\
    T data;\
}

CREATE_NAME_WRAPPER(MyInt, int);

int main() {
    int x = 3;
    MyInt y = 5;

    int z = x + y;

    std::cout << "x: " << x << ", y: " << y << ", z: " << z << '\n';
    std::cout << "z = x + y = " << z << '\n';
    std::cout << "typeid(y): " << typeid(y).name() << '\n';

    return 0;
}

Output:
x: 3, y: 5, z: 8
z = x + y = 8
typeid(y): 5MyInt

live example
